# Dplyr summarise different columns that do not have a group into one table

Tags: r, dplyr

I am currently working on two data sets that have nothing for me to group_by (and it is rather impossible to create a group_id). What I am trying to do is get a table that contains 4 columns (Sample Average, 75%ile, 25%ile, Average) for the selected columns.

| Sample Average | 75%ile | 25%ile | Average |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| mean(df1$`Impact`) | quant(df2$`Impact`, probs = 0.75) | quant(df2$`Impact`, probs = 0.25) | quant(df2$`Impact`, probs = 0.5) |
| mean(df1$`Test`) | quant(df2$`Test`, probs = 0.75) | quant(df2$`Test`, probs = 0.25) | quant(df2$`Test`, probs = 0.5) |

Currently, the way I am doing this is by:

```
    Impact <- modified.basic %>%
    summarise("Sample Mean" = mean(.$`Impact`),
            "75th %ile" = quantile(table.basic$`Impact`, probs = 0.75),
            "25th %ile" = quantile(table.basic$`Impact`, probs = 0.25),
            "Average" = quantile(table.basic$`Impact`, probs = 0.5)
  ) 
Testing <- modified.basic %>%
  summarise("Sample Mean" = mean(.$`Test`),
           "75th %ile" = quantile(table.basic$`Test`, probs = 0.75),
           "25th %ile" = quantile(table.basic$`Test`, probs = 0.25),
           "Average" = quantile(table.basic$`Test`, probs = 0.5)
  )

Ofcourse <- rbind(Impact,Testing)
```

However, I would simply like have everything in one pipeline if possible since I would end up with 10 summary tables. Furthermore, it would be nice to give each row a name but I do not know how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The base function `apply` can do this. See below for a few variations with some `rnorm` data.

```
> dat <- data.frame(impact = rnorm(100), test = rnorm(100))

> apply(dat, 2, quantile, c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75))
        impact        test
25% -1.0023553 -0.73010533
50% -0.1199214 -0.05900919
75%  0.4616268  0.65027525

> t(apply(dat, 2, quantile, c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)))
              25%         50%       75%
impact -1.0023553 -0.11992141 0.4616268
test   -0.7301053 -0.05900919 0.6502752

> apply(dat, 2, function(x) c(mean = mean(x), quantile(x, c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75))))
         impact        test
mean -0.2083003  0.01224065
25%  -1.0023553 -0.73010533
50%  -0.1199214 -0.05900919
75%   0.4616268  0.65027525

> t(apply(dat, 2, function(x) c(mean = mean(x), quantile(x, c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)))
))
              mean        25%         50%       75%
impact -0.20830026 -1.0023553 -0.11992141 0.4616268
test    0.01224065 -0.7301053 -0.05900919 0.6502752
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mentioned in the post that I am working with two different sets. Is there anyway to do what you did above with two different data.frames?

Comment: Can you just use two calls to `apply`? The two data frames could be `merge`d or combined with `cbind` but if there is no connection between them, I do not recommend it.